# Case When Exists query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying this in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.InteractionID, 
    a.Program, 
    a.[Client Name],
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM [Interaction Behaviors] 
            JOIN Behaviors 
                ON [Interaction Behaviors].BehaviorID = Behaviors.BehaviorID
            JOIN Interactions
                ON Interactions.InteractionID = [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID 
            WHERE 
                [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID = Interactions.InteractionID 
                AND Behaviors.BehaviorID = 1
            ) 
                THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS 'Alcohol/Drug Use By Client',
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM [Interaction Behaviors] JOIN 
            Behaviors 
                ON [Interaction Behaviors].BehaviorID = Behaviors.BehaviorID 
            JOIN Interactions 
                ON Interactions.InteractionID = [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID 
            WHERE 
                [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID = Interactions.InteractionID
                AND Behaviors.BehaviorID = 5
            ) 
                THEN Behavior 
        ELSE '' 
    END AS 'Allegation--Text', 
    c.InterventionID,
    d.Intervention ASIntervention_Name  
FROM (
    (
        [Interactions Query] AS a
        INNER JOIN  [Interaction Interventions] AS c 
            ON a.InteractionID = c.InteractionID
    )
LEFT JOIN Interventions AS d 
    ON c.InterventionID = d.InterventionID
```

The first `Case` statement executes fine.

The problem is in the second `Cas`e statement where I don't just want a 1 or 0 but the actual text.

For that one, I get an error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 Invalid column name 'Behavior'

`Behavior` is a column in the `[Interaction Behaviors]` table.

I understand that I need to explicitly join the `[Interaction Behaviors]` table in the from statement. However, doing so gives me odd duplicated rows so I need to take care of that in the `Case`.

Thanks for time!

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced, not to mention that the query isn't readable right now.

Comment: You can't access column `Behavior` out of subquery which contains this column. it is in `(SELECT * FROM [Interaction Behaviors] JOIN Behaviors ON [Interaction Behaviors].BehaviorID=Behaviors.BehaviorID JOIN Interactions on Interactions.InteractionID=[Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID WHERE [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID=Interactions.InteractionID AND Behaviors.BehaviorID=5)`

Comment: You are probably not aware of your subqueries not relating to your main records. I.e. in your subqueries you dont refer to table a, c or d. Either there exists a Behaviors record with BehaviorID = 1, then you show 1 for all selected records, or it doesn't and you show 0 for all rows. So maybe you should tell us what the query is *supposed* to do.

Comment: Is it possible for those subqueries to return *mutliple* rows? If so, how should we (in the second case) determine *which* behaviour to show?

Comment: Yes, I understand that Behavior is out of the subquery and not relating to the main records. That is the problem and joining [Interaction Behaviors] table to the main query only gives me duplicated rows. The subqueries should return only one row per person.  I had to edit the query I showed here to make it less complicated and to remove any identifying characteristics but it seems it's not the best example. I'll try to fix that and edit my example as well as add what results I'm expecting. Hopefully, that'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Behavior with the below code

```
                                (    SELECT Behavior  
                                FROM [Interaction Behaviors] JOIN 
                                Behaviors 
                                ON [Interaction Behaviors].BehaviorID = Behaviors.BehaviorID 
                                JOIN Interactions 
                                ON Interactions.InteractionID = [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID 
                                WHERE 
                                [Interaction Behaviors].InteractionID = Interactions.InteractionID
                                AND Behaviors.BehaviorID = 5
                                )
```

Comment: Thank you... this is the closest I've gotten but I then get this error message: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time but it's working now. Thank you for your help.